# How to get Excel Sheetname on Android without using CELL function

Tags: excel, function, formula, cell

I tried to get the sheetname using formula "=CELL("filename",A1)" which was successful on PC (Windows) but when I transferred the file to use on my mobile phone (Android), the value became error. After checking I found that Microsoft 365 mobile version doesn't recognize CELL function.

Could anyone suggest another way to get the sheetname without using CELL function please?

Note that would need this in automation as there will be 200 sheets (sheet 001 to sheet 200) and each will return its result to the Master sheet.

Thank you so much in advance.

CELL function works fine on PC (Windows)

[image]

But it's not recognized on Microsoft 365 (Android)

[image]